# class self acts like integer

Tags: python, class, integer, self

I didn't understand why. And It will raise an error 'int' object has no attribute 'v', but I want to access the self.v. When I print only self it will print some numbers. I couldn't understand what was going on. Here is my code.

```
class Candidate:
    def __init__(self,val,pscore,nscore):
        self.v = val
        self.p = pscore
        self.n = nscore

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.v} ({self.p},{self.n})"

    def check_plus_pos(self, guessval):
        count = 0
        b = self.v
        a = str(b)
        guessval = str(guessval)
        for i in range(0,len(a)):
            if a[i] == guessval[i]:
                count += 1
        return count

    def check_neg_pos(self, guessval):
        count = 0
        b = self.v
        a = str(b)

        guessval = str(guessval)
        for i in range(0,len(a)):
            for j in range(0,len(guessval)):
                if a[i] == guessval[j] and a[i] != guessval[i]:
                    count += 1
        return count

    def consistent(self, guess):
        if Candidate.check_plus_pos(self,guess.v) == guess.p and Candidate.check_neg_pos(self,guess.v) == guess.n:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The problem occurs at `b == self.v` I wanted to assign the `self.v` value to a variable.

Comment: Sounds like you never actually made an instance of your class.

Comment: You also can probably switch `Candidate.check_plus_pos(self,guess.v)` with `self.check_plus_pos(guess.v)`

Comment: How can I use an instance in here couldn't understand that.

Comment: `self` is the _instance_ of the class.  You typically instantiate the class in the code where you want to use it.

Comment: Okay but I want to use the value that is instantiated after the code and use the parameter of it. I hope I could expressed it :D

Comment: As written your question is unclear I'm afraid.  Please show more code, showing how you are using, or intend to use the `Candidate` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest it's pretty hard to understand what that code/class is supposed to do, imho it needs some serious refactoring.

My guess is you should:

- **instantiate** your class somewhere
- use the method as an instance method, so invoke it with `self` and not the class name
- do **NOT** pass `self` explicitly at all
- do **NOT** use abbreviations which are not commonly known
- do **NOT** use single letter variables `a` means literally nothing
- use docstrings for non-trivial functions (or as a rule of thumb to most of functions/methods)
- use type hints, which will help you catch this kind of errors automatically (if you configure your IDE that is)
- get rid of the assignment to `b` at all, it's not reused and doesn't seem do anything. This will do the same `a = str(self.v)`

```py
    ... # all the class related code above
    def check_neg_pos(self, guessval):
        count = 0
        a = str(self.v)

        guessval = str(guessval)
        for i in range(0,len(a)):
            for j in range(0,len(guessval)):
                if a[i] == guessval[j] and a[i] != guessval[i]:
                    count += 1
        return count

    def is_consistent(self, guess: Candidate)->bool:
        return bool(self.check_plus_pos(guess.v) == guess.p and self.check_neg_pos(guess.v) == guess.n)
# Example usage
candidate_1 = Candidate(1,2,3)
candidate_2 = Candidate(4,5,6)
candidates_consistent = candidate_1.is_consistent(guess=candidate_2)
print(candidates_consistent)
```